# cant select any object in blender (not even in a new file)

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, object-mode

I don't remember everything I did, but I do remember trying to delete my lamp and I couldn't select it. I tried moving an object around on the map but I couldn't even select it. the A key still select everything. I can still move things around when an object is already selected. so what I did is I gave up on that project and created a new one. I deleted the cube and added a plane. I went to edit mode and tried deleting the vertices. I couldn't even select it. does anyone know what I did or whats going on? I'm using Vr. 2.78.

Comment: This question is not clear. If you could delete the Cube then you could select it. If you could go into Edit Mode with the Plane then you could select it.

Comment: Possibly related : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/101969/29586

Comment: when you start a new project the cube is already selected for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like a strange keybind or something.  Maybe restore to defaults and try again w/ a new project?